# Javascript function doesn't do a transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make my list in my nav to have the transition applied.
    
*The call*

```
animate(0,"mainNav",.04,0.03);
```

*The function*

```
function animate(num, element, transitionUnit, delayUnit){
        var transition = 0;
        var delay = 0;
        var x = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');
        for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
                x[i].style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d("+num+"px,0px,0)";
                x[i].style.opacity = "1";
                x[i].style.transition = transition + "s " + delay +"s !important";
                delay += delayUnit;
                transition += transitionUnit;
            }
        }
```

This function applies changes to everything except that It just completely misses x[i].style.transition = ""; and x[i].innerHTML = "";

What could be the problem? I've tried changing everything including the querySelector, but this is what I've had found to work except the two I have mentioned above.

P.S. It works with

```
animate(0,"viewNav",.04,0.03);
```

I just need it to work with mainNav

Comment: You sure `transition` is defined at line 6?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 what do you mean by defined? It's a css property

Comment: `x[i].style.transition = transition...` In this line the `transition` after the equal sign is not defined in your sample code.

Comment: @Happy - I'm talking about the variable "transition" in `transition + "s " + delay +"s !important"`.

Comment: Also, I do not see that you are using the `element` argument of your function anywhere...

Comment: Maybe it is supposed to be something like `var el = document.getElementById(element); var x = el.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');`